# JavaScript: how to resize div.card

Tags: javascript

sorry for my bad english, hope you can understand what kind of problem do I have.
So, here is the code and what it does is to resize the div.cards. I mean, when I have the window on fullscreen the table shows correctly the div.cards. So, when I start to change the size of window, some of those cards changing the offsetHeight in some rows (always depends on the text on them). I've attached the image of my table (with non-fullscreen window). So, as you can see, when I changed my window, the cards are changed the offsetHeight so, what I already achieved is to apply the same height to all div.cards with the most tallest div.card in the row. Where I'm still stuck, is: when I return the window to the fullscreen, those div.cards should go back to their original offsetHeight, but still unable to understand how to do that.

I was already tried, like putting the offsetHeight of all my div.cards into array then restore them somehow, but no success. 
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuD7r.jpg)

```
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            var row, n, column, m, mColumn, t;
            var maxOffSet = 0, minOffSet = 0;
            for (row = 0, n = table.rows.length; row < n; row++) {
                for (column = 0, m = table.rows[row].cells.length; column < m; column++) {
                    console.log('Row: ' + [row] + ' Column:' + [column] + ' clHeight: ' + table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight);
                    // if (maxOffSet < table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight) {
                    //     maxOffSet = table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight;
                    // }
                }
                // table.rows[row].style.minHeight = maxOffSet;
                // for (mColumn = 0, t = table.rows[row].cells.length; mColumn < t; mColumn++) {
                //     table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[mColumn].style.height = maxOffSet + 'px';
                // }
            }
        };
```

**HTML:**

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="ragioneria_da_smistare_todo">1</span><span class="counter" id="ragioneria_da_smistare_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span><span class="stagestext" id="ragioneria_da_smistare_Descr">Ragioneria da smistare</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="ragioneria_rifiutati_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="ragioneria_rifiutati_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span><span class="stagestext" id="ragioneria_rifiutati_Descr">Ragioneria rifiutati</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="responsabile_da_smistare_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="responsabile_da_smistare_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="responsabile_da_smistare_Descr">Responsabile da smistare</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="ufficio_di_competenza_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="ufficio_di_competenza_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="ufficio_di_competenza_Descr">Ufficio di competenza</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="responsabile_appr_pagamento_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="responsabile_appr_pagamento_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="responsabile_appr_pagamento_Descr">Responsabile approvazione pagamento</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="ragioneria_appr_pagamento_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="ragioneria_appr_pagamento_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="ragioneria_appr_pagamento_Descr">Ragioneria approvazione pagamento</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="direzione_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="direzione_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="direzione_Descr">Direzione</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="presidenza_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="presidenza_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="presidenza_Descr">Presidenza</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="sospesa_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="sospesa_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="sospesa_Descr">Sospesa</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="ragioneria_rifiuta_pagamento_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="ragioneria_rifiuta_pagamento_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="ragioneria_rifiuta_pagamento_Descr">Ragioneria rifiuta pagamento</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="ragioneria_da_pagare_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="ragioneria_da_pagare_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="ragioneria_da_pagare_Descr">Ragioneria da pagare</span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content"> <span class="counterComp" id="ragioneria_pagam_parziale_todo">0</span><span class="counter" id="ragioneria_pagam_parziale_watch">(0)&nbsp;</span> <span class="stagestext" id="ragioneria_pagam_parziale_Descr">Ragioneria pagamento parziale</span>
 </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .card {
                /*max-width: 500px*/;
                margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                /*max-height: 60px;*/
                position: relative;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
                -webkit-box-direction: normal;
                -ms-flex-direction: row;
                flex-direction: row;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                min-width: 0;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                background-color: #fff;
                background-clip: border-box;
                border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
                border-radius: .25rem;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
                box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
            }

            .card-body {
                flex: 1 1 auto;
                min-height: 1px;
                padding: 1rem;
                /*display: flex;*/
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .content {
                display: table;
                /*width: 75%;*/
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .content > span {
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
```

**CSS-JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerHTML = '\
                body {\
                    display: none;\
                }\
                .logo-div {\
                    background-image: url(view.do?id=1041&className=LOGO);\
                    height: 200px;\
                    width: auto;\
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;\
                    background-origin: content-box;\
                    background-position: center;\
                    margin-bottom: 5px;\
                    /*border-bottom: 5px solid #ef5114;*/\
                }\
                .stagestext {\
                    color: #ef5114;\
                    font-weight: bold;\
                    font-size: 1.3em;\
                    vertical-align: 10%;\
                    text-align: start;\
                    padding-left: 20px;\
                    /*padding-right: 20%;*/\
                }\
                .datetext {\
                    color: #546E7A;\
                    font-weight: bold;\
                    font-size: 1.5em;\
                }\
                .counter {\
                    /*border-right: 5px solid #1bb0e1;*/\
                    font-size: 2em;\
                    color: #1bb0e1;\
                    /*padding-left: 5px;*/\
                    /*cursor: pointer;*/\
                    width: 10%;\
                }\
                .counterComp {\
                    font-size: 2em;\
                    color: #1bb0e1;\
                    /*padding-right: 5px;*/\
                    /*cursor: pointer;*/\
                    width: 10%;\
                }\
                .counter.error {\
                    border-left-color: red;\
                    color: red;\
                }\
                .counter.warning {\
                    border-left-color: orange;\
                    color: orange;\
                }\
                .counter.success {\
                    border-left-color: green;\
                    color: green;\
                }\
                .badge-table {\
                    width: 100%;\
                    /*border-bottom\: 5px solid #ef5114;*/\
                }\
                /*.badge-table tbody tr td {\
                    padding: padding: 5px 3px;\
                }*/\
                .datacorrente-table {\
                    width: 100%;\
                    /*border-bottom\: 5px solid #ef5114;*/\
                }\
                .datacorrente-table tbody tr td {\
                    padding-top: 5px;\
                    padding-right: 5px;\
                    padding-left: 5px;\
                    padding-bottom: 10px;\
                    width: 25%\
                }\
                .badge-title {\
                    font-size: 2em;\
                    vertical-align: middle;\
                    width: 100%;\
                }\
                .template-div {\
                    display: inline-block;\
                    border-radius: 6px;\
                    color: #ffffff;\
                    text-align: left;\
                }\
                .padder-div {\
                    padding-left: 10px;\
                    padding-right: 10px;\
                }\
                .column-left {\
                    width: 49.5%;\
                    float: left;\
                    display: inline-block;\
                }\
                .column-right {\
                    width: 49.5%;\
                    float: right;\
                    display: inline-block;\
                }\
                .label-left{\
                    padding-left: 10px;\
                    font-size: 15px;\
                    display: inline-block;\
                }\
                .label-right{\
                    padding-right: 10px;\
                    font-size: 15px;\
                    float: right;\
                }\
                .dashboard-divider{\
                    padding-left: 10px;\
                    padding-right: 10px;\
                }\
                #title-card {\
                    width: 100%;\
                    background-color: rgb(158, 158, 158);\
                    border-width: 1px;\
                    text-align: center;\
                }\
                #table-div{\
                    width: 100%;\
                    border-width: 1px;\
                    text-align: center;\
                }\
                td {\
                    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;\
                }\
            ';
```

**UPDATE**
I modified the javascript, but the window has becomed very laggy :(

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
            resetTable();
            resizeTable();
        });

        function resetTable() {
            console.log('Rows: ' + document.getElementById("table").rows.length);
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            var row, n, column, m;
            for (row = 0, n = table.rows.length; row < n; row++) {
                for (column = 0, m = table.rows[row].cells.length; column < m; column++) {
                    console.log('Row: ' + [row] + ' Column:' + [column] + ' clHeight: ' + table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight);
                    table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].style.minHeight = 'auto';
                }
            }
        }

        function resizeTable() {
            console.log('Rows: ' + document.getElementById("table").rows.length);
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            var row, n, column, m, mColumn, t;
            var maxOffSet = 0;
            for (row = 0, n = table.rows.length; row < n; row++) {
                for (column = 0, m = table.rows[row].cells.length; column < m; column++) {
                    console.log('Row: ' + [row] + ' Column:' + [column] + ' clHeight: ' + table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight);
                    if (maxOffSet < table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight) {
                        maxOffSet = table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight;
                    }
                }
                for (mColumn = 0, t = table.rows[row].cells.length; mColumn < t; mColumn++) {
                    // var t = maxOffSetRow - table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[mColumn].offsetHeight;
                    table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[mColumn].style.minHeight = maxOffSet + 'px';
                    table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[mColumn].style.minHeight = 'auto';
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE** nevermind, I've commented my console.log outputs and it's works like a charm. So solve it by myself :D

Comment: Could you please add your html and css

Comment: Just to better understand it's a requirement that all cards have always the same height right? If you just need to have same heights in a row you could just add two small things to your css and completely remove the js part: `.card { height: 100%; } td { height: 0px }`  https://codepen.io/Mindcraft1/pen/bGVzEEE

Comment: thanks for the reply, resolve it by myself with the JS part as my company asked :)

Comment: please add an answer to your question with the solution to help others with similar problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:basically I introduced an array which stores the max OffsetHeight in the row, then applies it to all div.cards, after finishing the row it's cleanups so he can fill the data for the new row eccetera...

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
                resetTable();
                resizeTable();
            });

        function resetTable() {
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            var row, n, column, m;
            for (row = 0, n = table.rows.length; row < n; row++) {
                for (column = 0, m = table.rows[row].cells.length; column < m; column++) {
                    //console.log('Row: ' + [row] + ' Column:' + [column] + ' clHeight: ' + table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight);
                    table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].style.minHeight = 'auto';
                }
            }
        }

        function resizeTable() {
            //console.log('Rows: ' + document.getElementById("table").rows.length);
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            var row, n, column, m, mColumn, t, arr = [];
            for (row = 0, n = table.rows.length; row < n; row++) {
                for (column = 0, m = table.rows[row].cells.length; column < m; column++) {
                    //console.log('Row: ' + [row] + ' Column:' + [column] + ' clHeight: ' + table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight);
                    arr.push(table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[column].offsetHeight);
                }
                for (mColumn = 0, t = table.rows[row].cells.length; mColumn < t; mColumn++) {
                    //console.log('Row: ' + [row] + ' Column:' + [mColumn] + ' clHeight: ' + Math.max.apply(Math, arr));
                    table.rows[row].getElementsByClassName("card")[mColumn].style.minHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, arr) + 'px';
                }
                arr = [];
            }
        }
```